# Why is foldr not returning undefined when folding over a list containing undefined?

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, fold

I'm having trouble understanding why the following:

```
foldr (\x y -> x && y) True [False,undefined,True]
```

is **not** giving me an `undefined` exception.

How I see it is, `foldr` compares `True` and the last element of the list, which would be `True`, thus returning `True` and now comparing it to `undefined`. Does Haskell ignore the operation if it involves an `undefined` type? I'd understand that the output were `True` if in the anonymous function we had `x || y` instead of `(&&)`, since the compiler would see that one of the operators is already set to `True`, but since we're working with an `(&&)` it has to check that both values are set to `True` or one of them to `False`, right?

Any clue as to why it returns `False`?

Comment: `undefined` is never ignored, unless in that situation every possible value would be ignored.

Comment: `undefined :: a` is not a type but a value of type `Bool` (in your case). In fact every type in Haskell has an additional value called ⊥ or [Bottom](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom). `Bool` therefore has the 3(!) values `True, False, ⊥`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not ignoring `undefined` so much as `undefined` is never seen.

The real definition of `foldr` is slightly more complicated, but we can pretend that it is defined (in part) as

```
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

Thus, after one step, we have

```
foldr (&&) True [False, undefined, True]
  == False && foldr (&&) True [undefined, True]
```

Since `False && _ == False`, there is no need to evaluate the recursive call to `foldr`, and thus no need to do anything with `undefined`.

---

`undefined` only raises an exception if it is *evaluated*. It doesn't need to be evaluated to define the list `[False, undefined, True]`, which is syntactic sugar for `False : undefined : True : []`, and `(:)` is lazy in its second argument.

Comment: Doesn't `foldr` start from the last element of the list? As in: `True` && `True`, then `undefined` and finally `False`

Comment: No, that's `foldl`. The `r` refers to which part is recursively folded before applying the fold function to the result and the remaining element.

Comment: It's a common misconception, that fooled me for a minute while I was first looking at this. But *both* `foldl` *and* `foldl` "start from" the *first* element of the list. The "right"/"left" in the names doesn't refer to "which end of the list to start from", but how the fold function is associated. `foldr f acc [x,y,z]` is `f x (f y (f z acc))`, whereas `foldl` with the same arguments is `f (f (f acc x) y) z`.

Comment: `foldl` is a little trickier to write, since lists themselves are inherently right associative (`[x,y,z] == x : y : z : [] == x : (y : (z : []))`).

Answer (score 1):

The  code is equivalent to

```
let {w = [head w,True]} in foldr (&&) True (False:w)
===
let {w = [head w,True] ; 
     r = foldr (&&) True w} in False && r
===
let {r=r} in False
===
False
```

`foldr`-created calculations only process the input list from the right if the combining function is strict in its second (right) argument.

Here `(&&)` is not. It is "short-circuiting", immediately returning `False` in case its first argument is `False`, as it is here indeed. The `r` is never forced, as its value is not needed.